# Flink 1.13.2 running on ververica 2.5.1 - state contains absolute paths when saved to S3

Tags: apache-flink

According to the flink [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/savepoints/), since 1.11 savepoints should contain relative paths.

```
Sink Flink 1.11.0, savepoints are self-contained and relocatable. You can move the file and restore from any location.
```

I have a ververica cluster configured to save savepoints & checkpoints to S3 via

```
state.savepoints.dir = s3://<redacted>/savepoints
state.checkpoints.dir = s3://<redacted>/checkpoints
```

When I open the _metadata file, for both checkpoints and savepoints, I see absolute paths to S3 instead of relative paths. This makes altering the state locally a nightmare.

Is there a way to instruct ververica and/or flink to save with relative paths?

Comment: I believe there are IDs in the metadata that look like paths, but are simply IDs that shouldn't affect relocation. Are you sure there's a problem?

Comment: yes, I think it is a problem. When amending the state locally and then saving it, it looks for s3 files, then an exception is thrown asking to import either hadoop or presto because it needs access to S3. The metadata has s3 links inside it for the data files.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share such a savepoint?

Comment: One more idea: copy the savepoint to another location on your S3 without any further modification, then try to resume your job from the new savepoint. If it works, then relocation itself is fine, the problem is the amending part.

Comment: @qinjunjerry I already tried to save without amending anything and the same error was thrown. I will ask around if I can share that savepoint

Comment: I meant: copy the savepoint to another location on your S3, do not use state processor API at all, then try to resume your job directly from the copied savepoint. Would it work?